# Multiple rows in single field not getting loaded | SQL Loader | Oracle

Tags: oracle, unix, ksh, sql-loader

I need to load from **CSV** file into an Oracle Table.
The problem i m facing is that, the **DESCRIPTION** field is having Multiple Lines in itself.

Solution i am using for it as ENCLOSURE STRING `"` (Double Quotes)
Using **KSH** to call for sqlldr.

I am getting following two problems:

- The row having Description with multiple lines, is not getting loaded as it terminates there itself and values of further fields/columns are not visible for loader. **ERROR: second enclosure string not present** (Obviously `"` is not found.)
- The second line(and lines beyond that) of DESCRIPTION field is being treated as NEW Row in itself and is thus getting populated. It is GARBAGE DATA.

**CONTROL File:**

```
OPTIONS(SKIP=1)
LOAD DATA
        BADFILE '/home/fimsctl/datafiles/inbound/core_po/logs/core_po_data.bad'
        DISCARDFILE '/home/fimsctl/datafiles/inbound/core_po/logs/core_po_data.dsc'
        APPEND INTO TABLE FIMS_OWNER.FINANCE_PO_INBOUND_T
        FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
        TRAILING NULLCOLS
        (
          PO_NUM,
          CREATED_DATE "to_Date(:CREATED_DATE,'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss')",
          PO_TYPE,
          PO_STATUS,
          NOTREQ1 FILLER,
          NOTREQ2 FILLER,
          PO_VALUE,
          LINE_ITEM_NUMBER,
          QUANTITY,
          LINE_ITEM_DESCRIPTION,
          RATE_VALUE,
          CURRENCY_CODE,
          UOM_ID,
          PO_REQUESTER_WWID,
          QUANTITY_ORDERED,
          QUANTITY_RECEIVED,
          QUANTITY_BILLED terminated by whitespace
         )
```

**CSV File Data:**

```
COL1,8/4/2014 5:52,COL3,COL4,COL5,,,COL8,COL9,"Description Data",COL11,COL12,COL13,COL14,COL15,COL16,COL17

COL1,8/4/2014 8:07,COL3,COL4,COL5,,,COL8,COL9,,"GE MAKE 1X250 WATT HPSV NON INTEGRAL IP-65 **[NEWLINE HERE]**
DIE-CAST ALUMINIUM FIXTURE COMPLETE SET **[NEWLINE HERE]**
WITH SEPRATE CONTROL GEAR BOX WITH CHOKE, **[NEWLINE HERE]**
IGNITOR, CAPACITOR & LAMP-T",COL11,COL12,COL13,COL14,COL15,COL16,COL17

COL1,8/4/2014 8:13,COL3,COL4,COL5,,,COL8,COL9,"Description Data",COL11,COL12,COL13,COL14,COL15,COL16,COL17
```

Comment: How do *you* identify that that row is split? ie, at a basic level, how do you know that "IGNITOR" isn't supposed to be COL1 ?  Basically you need some check condition to know that you haven't finished yet.  When you do, you can use CONTINUEIF option:  http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14215/ldr_control_file.htm#sthref786

Comment: I'd seen CONTINUEIF, and it's seeming of no help(to me)... The data is coming from remote server and getting stored as CSV file. So can't say on what condition i can check for muliple lies or not... No control over the type of data in Description field.

Comment: Is there any difference between the line breaks within strings and between records - does one also have a carriage return? Long shot but just a thought... Is there any possibility of getting the file format changed so every field, or at least the last field, is enclosed in double quotes, or to have some dummy marker tacked on the end of each row?

Comment: Yes perhaps, that can be done(hope to make them convince!).. I's also thinking bout putting a dummy marker or to set different terminator. For now, I can't say, but urge to tell the all possible cases(I might need to give them options which they can do feasibly with the CSV file)

Comment: What are some sample (valid) values for COL1 ?   No idea what's in there, however, it might be useful ?

Comment: I was also looking for a way to say "CONTINUEIF <last field is NULL>" .. but I couldn't see a way to do that? Did I miss something in the docs ? [edit] I keep seeing this:  CONTINUEIF LAST PRESERVE !=''  not sure if that would work .. or not. [/edit] [edit2] meant empty string, not quote .. [/edit2]

Comment: Managed for(kinda oral approval) putting DESCRIPTION field(field havign multiple line) to be sent as LAST Column in file. Next try shall be for changing the record delimiter other than newline to something ~ or ^

Comment: @Sachin - the delimiter woudl have to be something that can't appear in a description though; of those a dash is most likely to perhaps. But if the description moved to the end of the file then you can use `continueif` based on whether the last char of the line is `"`, no? So that change on its own ought to be enough.

Comment: duplicate: http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/182897/4667