# loading data in table using SQL Loader

Tags: oracle, sql-loader

I'm loading data into my table through SQL Loader
data loading is successful but i''m getting garbage(repetitive) value in a particular column for all rows

After inserting :
column **TERM_AGREEMENT** is getting value '806158336' for every record
My csv file contains atmost 3 digit data for that column,but i'm forced to set my column definition to Number(10).

```
   LOAD DATA
    infile '/ipoapplication/utl_file/LBR_HE_Mar16.csv'
    REPLACE
    INTO TABLE LOAN_BALANCE_MASTER_INT
    fields terminated by ',' optionally enclosed by '"'
    (
    ACCOUNT_NO,
    CUSTOMER_NAME,
    LIMIT,
    REGION,

    **TERM_AGREEMENT INTEGER**
    )
```

```
create table LOAN_BALANCE_MASTER_INT
(
  ACCOUNT_NO             NUMBER(30),
  CUSTOMER_NAME          VARCHAR2(70),
  LIMIT                  NUMBER(30),

  PRODUCT_DESC           VARCHAR2(30),
  SUBPRODUCT_CODE        NUMBER,

  ARREARS_INT            NUMBER(20,2),
  IRREGULARITY           NUMBER(20,2),
  PRINCIPLE_IRREGULARITY NUMBER(20,2),


  **TERM_AGREEMENT         NUMBER(10)**
)
```

Comment: Could `806158336` be the account number of the next line?

Comment: no,account number is only of 7 digits.And how it's giving me the same value for 3987 rows? I even ran the following command(AIX):  cat LBR_HE_Mar16.csv | grep 806158336 ,and there were no records found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually solved this issue on my own.
Firstly, thanks to @Gary_W AND @Alessandro for their inputs.Really appreciate your help guys,learned some new things in the process.
Here's the new fragment which worked and i got the correct data for the last column

```
 LOAD DATA
    infile '/ipoapplication/utl_file/LBR_HE_Mar16.csv'
    REPLACE
    INTO TABLE LOAN_BALANCE_MASTER_INT
    fields terminated by ',' optionally enclosed by '"'
    (
    ACCOUNT_NO,
    CUSTOMER_NAME,
    LIMIT,
    REGION,

    **TERM_AGREEMENT INTEGER Terminated by Whitspace**
    )
```

- 'Terminated by whitespace' - I went through some threads of SQL Loader and i used 'terminated by whitespace' in the last column of his ctl file. it worked ,this time i didn't even had to use 'INTEGER' or 'EXTERNAL' or EXPRESSION '..' for conversion.
  Just one thing, now can you guys let me now what could possibly be creating issue ?what was there in my csv file in that column and how by adding this thing solved the issue ?
  Thanks.

Comment: used this as reference 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28323414/multiple-rows-in-single-field-not-getting-loaded-sql-loader-oracle?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

INTEGER is for binary data type. If you're importing a csv file, I suppose the numbers are stored as plain text, so you should use INTEGER EXTERNAL. The EXTERNAL clause specifies character data that represents a number.

Edit: 
The issue seems to be the termination character of the file. You should be able to solve this issue by editing the INFILE line this way:

```
INFILE'/ipoapplication/utl_file/LBR_HE_Mar16.csv' "STR X'5E204D'"
```

Where '5E204D' is the hexadecimal for '^ M'. To get the hexadecimal value you can use the following query:

```
SELECT utl_raw.cast_to_raw ('^ M') AS hexadecimal FROM dual;
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: i used INTEGER because without it i was getting the error ORA-01722: invalid number ,even though in my csv file i changed it's datatype to 'General' . Even with INTEGER EXTERNAL i'm getting same error,records are getting rejected.

Comment: If you can provide a line of example of your csv, it would help solving the issue.

Comment: :file on server:
3041295,Mr. ASHVINBHAI PRAVINBHAI DESAI,600000,WEST,216,SURAT BRANCH,1,29-Jan-09,03-Jan-21,7201,7201-HOME EQUITY,101,HOME EQUITY FINANCE - RES,Fully Advanced,80
5816,19.25,600000,381412,381386,381386,0,0,0,0,-27,0,0,0,03-Feb-09,10239,02-Apr-16,03-Apr-16,58,85,0,0,0,ECS,PROCESSED,,3,29-Jan-09,0,0,0,,1171.26,120,N,1,AKOPD2862M,0^
M

Comment: i believe that '^M' in the end is an issue ,when the file is ftped on server.I read somewhere to use 'dos2unix' for it but i'm getting 'command not found' error. How come i'm getting those characters in the end when i put the file on server?

Comment: Now i'm getting this 
SQL*Loader-510: Physical record in data file (/ipoapplication/utl_file/HEr16.csv) is longer than the maximum(1048576)
SQL*Loader-2026: the load was aborted because SQL Loader cannot continue.

Comment: I read somewhere and increased the readsize ,but then it is only reading one record and giving the error 'Invalid number' on the same column.

Comment: @arjun gaur Try just `"str x'0D'"` as I doubt there is really a space in there.

Comment: @Gary_W same garbage value there.
But this time a different one '805306368',as usual ,same for all 4k rows.

Comment: @gary_w  , guys it worked, i figured it out. posted an answer, request you to vote up if it's correct, so that it helps others if they encounter such issue .Thanks.

Comment: @Alessandro Vacchio , figured it out, please go through the answer i put up.Thanks